# How to sort an array by a specific key

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using swapi.co as my source of json data and my response looks like the following: https://swapi.co/api/people/

My array of "characters" has the structure

```
// MARK: - CharactersResult
struct CharactersResult: Codable {
    let name, height, mass, hairColor: String
    let skinColor, eyeColor, birthYear: String
    let gender: Gender
    let homeworld: String
    let films, species, vehicles, starships: [String]
    let created, edited: String
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, height, mass
        case hairColor = "hair_color"
        case skinColor = "skin_color"
        case eyeColor = "eye_color"
        case birthYear = "birth_year"
        case gender, homeworld, films, species, vehicles, starships, created, edited, url
    }
}
```

I would like to get the **smallest** character and the **largest** out of my array. My function is:

```
func getCharacters(urlToGet: String){
            do{
                if let url = URL(string: urlToGet) {
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                        if let data = data {
                            do {
                                let jsonCharacters = try JSONDecoder().decode(Characters.self, from: data)



                                self.characters = self.characters + jsonCharacters.results

                                self.nextPageUrlForCharacters = jsonCharacters.next

                                self.updatePicker()

                            } catch let error {
                                print(error)


                            }
                        }
                        }.resume()

                }
            }
        }
```

My main question is where to do the sorting and what is the most efficient way to get the smallest and the largest character.

Comment: You want to get all of your results and then use the `reduce` function to get the smallest or largest. What do you mean by length? What makes a CharactersResult short or long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming *smallest* and *largest* is related to the height of the character (then *shortest* and *tallest* are more appropriate), sort the array by that struct member. As the value is `String` you have to add the `.numeric` option.

The *descending* order starts with the largest value

```
let sortedCharacters = self.characters.sorted{$0.height.compare($1.height, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending}
let tallestCharacter = sortedCharacters.first
let shortestCharacter = sortedCharacters.last
```

Side note: You can get rid of the CodingKeys if you add the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This simplified version of your code illustrates how to sort by an arbitrary key, as long as that key is `Comparable` (so I've made your `height` and `mass` properties both `Int`s rather than `String`):

```
struct MovieCharacter: Codable {
    let name: String
    let height: Int
    let mass: Int
}

let fred = MovieCharacter(name: "Fred", height: 123, mass: 99)
let wilma = MovieCharacter(name: "Wilma", height: 158, mass: 47)

let chars = [fred, wilma]

let heaviestToLightest = chars.sorted { $0.mass > $1.mass }
// Prints "Fred, Wilma"
print(heaviestToLightest.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: ", "))

let tallestToShortest = chars.sorted { $0.height > $1.height }
// prints "Wilma, Fred"
print(tallestToShortest.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: ", "))
```

To change the sort order, reverse the `>' in the comparison closure. If you want to know the "most" and "least" of a particular order, use`.first`and`.last` on the result.

Also, to save yourself from having to maintain the `CodingKeys` enum, use `.keyDecodingStrategy` of a `JSONDecoder`:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let characters = try decoder.decode(Characters.self, from: jsonData)
```